Question on arabic grammar
Maalik reported in al-Muwatta’ that the Messenger of Allah
($£) said: “O Allah! Do not make my grave an idol that would be
worshipped. Allah’s anger became deep against the people who took
the graves of their Prophets as places of worship.
His saying: “O Allah, Allahumma: its etymology isyaa Allah! (O Allah);
so the vocative, yaa was omitted in order to start with Allah’s Name and
the letter, meem was added to it to express plurality. Thus, it is as if the
caller turned all his attention and hope towards Allah. The meem occurs
at the end so that it could start with the Name of Allah.
This is an extract from the english Explanation of Kitab at Tawheed by Shaikh ibn Uthaymeen page 428 and 429. Can someone please explain what do we mean by plurality here? I mean the plurality of what is meant here?
